# Can valueForKeyPath compute the maximum of sums?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kvc

I have the following Objective-C class:

```
@interface GraphDataPoint : NSObject
@property NSDate *date;
@property NSNumber *value;
@end
```

Given an `NSArray` of `GraphDataPoint`, I know how to calculate the maximum `value` using

```
[data valueForKeyPath:@"@max.value"]
```

Now I want to change `value` to an array of `values`:

```
@property NSArray *values;
```

Is there a similar way to compute the maximum of the *sum* of the `value` property of each `GraphDataPoint` in an `NSArray` using `valueForKeyPath`? (I know I can write a nested loop to work it out manually.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
NSArray *a = @[
    [[GraphDataPoint alloc] initWithVal:@[@1, @2, @3]] // Sum=6
,   [[GraphDataPoint alloc] initWithVal:@[@4, @1, @1]] // Sum=6
,   [[GraphDataPoint alloc] initWithVal:@[@5, @4, @7]] // Sum=16
,   [[GraphDataPoint alloc] initWithVal:@[@6, @8, @9]] // Sum=23 <<== Max
,   [[GraphDataPoint alloc] initWithVal:@[@7, @6, @2]] // Sum=15
];

NSNumber *res = [a valueForKeyPath:@"@max.value.@sum.intValue"];
NSLog(@"Res: %@", res); // This prints 23
```

Comment: I'm afraid not, I get a similar error: `reason: '[<GraphDataPoint 0x8c79350> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key @sum.'`. I still need to use the `GraphDataPoint` class.

Comment: @GregHewgill I fixed that - it worked in my setup (I added `initWithVal:` initializer that takes an `NSArray*` of `NSNumber*` objects).

Comment: You beat me to it! - Note that if you use `@"@max.values.@sum.self"` as key path then it works with arbitrary numbers and not just integers.

Comment: That was it, thanks! My values are actually `double`, so `@max.values.@sum.self` works well.